Problem with sending FormData with HttpClient from Angular 18 to FastAPI
As described in the title, I am trying to send a file via FormData from an Angular 18 Frontend to a FastAPI Backend.
My code in Angular:
uploadFile(fileFormData: FormData) {
    const url: string = this.api_url;

    const body =
    {
      upload_file: fileFormData
    };

    return this.httpClient.post(url, body);
}

My code in FastAPI:
@app.post("/upload")
async def upload(upload_file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    if upload_file:

        return status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED

    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)

This is the result when sending the API Request:
Status: 422 Unprocessable Content
    
Response details:
{"detail":[{"type":"missing","loc":["body","upload_file"],"msg":"Field required","input":null}]}

So according to the response details the problem should be clear - but how to fix this?
In my Angular code the apparently missing field "upload_file" is provided in the body for the post request, so that should be correct.
I already tried playing with the content type in header information but without luck.
Does anyone have an idea what I could do to get this fixed and running?
Thank you very much in advance.
Cheers

are you sure fileFormData can be given as param just like that?

This, as well as this and this might also help you.

Upload the file using FormData instead of sending it through the body as is.
uploadFile(fileFormData: FormData) {
  const url: string = this.api_url;
  const fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('upload_file', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
  return this.httpClient.post(url, fd);
}

Reference Stackblitz

That fixed it!
It can be so easy ...
Thank you very much.
